# If condition matches append to line

Tags: awk

I have a tab delim file

```
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4017    2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC
```

I wanna add "`fixed`" to the lines where alternate cols `$4,$6,$8,$10,$12` are the same, else add "`var`".
So that the output is

```
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  var    
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      2       GG      0       TT  var   
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  fixed   
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  fixed    
NC_044998.1     4017    2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC  fixed
```

I'm currently using this modification of an answer to a similar question I had posted.

```
awk -F '\t' '{for (i=6; i<=24; i+=2) if ($i == $4) print $0,"fixed"; else print $0,"var"}'
```

But it doesn't it seems to be only looking at the first `i` in the loop.

Comment: Yes, fixed the example now. thxs

Comment: Why are you printing inside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak your attempt a bit like this:

```sh
awk -v fpos="4 6 8 10 12" 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
   split(fpos, flds, / /)
}
{
   for (i in flds)
      if ( $(flds[i]) != $(flds[1]) ) {
         print $0, "var"
         next
      }
   print $0, "fixed"
}' file
```

```
NC_044998.1 4015    0   TT  2   GG  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT var
NC_044998.1 4015    0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  2   GG  0   TT var
NC_044998.1 4016    0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT fixed
NC_044998.1 4016    0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT fixed
NC_044998.1 4017    2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC fixed
```

---

If filed positions always increment by 2 then you may use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = "\t"
}
{
   for (i=6; i<=12; i+=2)
      if ($i != $4) {
         print $0, "var"
         next
      }
      print $0, "fixed"
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you! This works and is closer to the strategy I was trying before :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using *conditional operator* in the `print`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
    print $0,($4==$6 && $6==$8 && $8==$10 && $10==$12?"fixed":"var")
}' file
```

Output:

```
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      var
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      var
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      fixed
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      fixed
NC_044998.1     4017    2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      fixed
```

Your method would work like this:

```
$ awk -F '\t' '{
    for(i=4;i<12;i+=2)       # loop from 4 to ... not 12
        if($i!=$(i+2)) {     # if i and next meaningful field do not equal
            print $0,"var"   # output var
            next             # and jump to next record
        } 
    print $0,"fixed"         # if loop is passed without next, its fixed
}' file
```